# Can not parse rss feed xml content using retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

This is my website rss feed structure. Trying to parse this using Retrofit2 XML Convert Factory.

```
<rss>
   <channel>
      <item>
         <title></title>
         <link></link>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title></title>
         <link></link>
      </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

Always getting following error:

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'title' does not have a match in class com.example.android.model.FeedChannel at line -1

Here is my data class:

```
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
data class FeedChannelData @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:Element(name = "channel")
    @param:Element(name = "channel")
    val feedChannel: FeedChannel? = null
)

@Root(name = "channel", strict = true)
data class FeedChannel @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:ElementList(name ="item", inline = true)
    @param:ElementList(name ="item", inline = true)
    var itemList: List<Item>? = null
)

@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
data class Item @JvmOverloads constructor(

    @field:Element(name = "title", required = true)
    @param:Element(name = "title", required = true)
    val title: String = "",

    @field:Element(name = "link", required = true)
    @param:Element(name = "link", required = true)
    val link: String= ""
)
```

Comment: Are you sure your RSS file does not have a <title> element inside <channel>?

Comment: @yole <channel> tag has its own <title> element. But what I want is the <title> element present inside <item>.

Comment: The exception is thrown because the <title> of the channel has no matching declaration in your data class, so you need to add it.

Comment: @yole can you please share sample code?

Comment: Copy/pasting the `title` property from `Item` into `FeedChannel` should work.